# make apache felix web console available remotely

Tags: jetty, osgi, apache-felix

I am working on a project that uses the apache felix webconsole with Jetty. The project uses the OSGi framework and is built using BND tools in eclipse. How can I configure jetty to allow connections from anywhere so I can use the webconsole when it is running remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the webconsole is available remotely by default.

If you need a configuration then it will be for felix http:

```
org.apache.felix.http.jettyEnabled=true
```

This is what I use. See the [felix http service docs](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#configuration-properties) for a list of configs.

I think the config property needed is `org.apache.felix.http.host` but the default seems to be to listen to all interfaces.